# How to make an S3 object public using AWS Java SDK V2?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

How do you make an S3 object public via the AWS Java SDK V2.2.41?

Specifically, what API methods via the Java AWS SDK V2 can be used to make an Object public when it's being uploaded or we make an existing uploaded object publicly readable?

Comment: did you check the api documentation ? It is pretty clear...you'll find all responses you need without the need to ask this question on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Well, at last found the answer: We can use

.acl(ObjectCannedACL.PUBLIC_READ)

with PutObjectRequest as under:

```
    PutObjectResponse putObjRes = s3Client.putObject(
            PutObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket("bucket")
                    .key("key)
                    .acl(ObjectCannedACL.PUBLIC_READ)
                    .build(), RequestBody.fromFile(<file>));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead property to create public objects through AWS Java SDK.

```
s3client.putObject(putObjectRequest.withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead))
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not available in SDK V2. This is V1 code.